# jquery $(this) instead of $('#id form)

Tags: jquery, this

I'm doing this:

```
$("#bcdialog").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
        'cancel': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } 
        'save': function() { $("#bcdialog form").submit(); }
        }
    });
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use this for the save function  instead of `#bcdialog form`

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? Do you want to add new "events" to the dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps giving it context of `this` will work, you'd still need to specify the form part, but giving it context makes it specific to the selector you've specified and you don't have to hard code the element id.

```
$("#bcdialog").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
        'cancel': function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } 
        'save': function() { $("form",this).submit(); }
        }
    });
```

:-)

Comment: it works, i just have to wait for 7 minutes until i can accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:
`$("form", this).submit();`

Comment: That won't work, as the context argument of the selector should be the parent of the selector itself. TI should be `div > form`, not `form > div` **edit** ok, someone's changed it

Comment: yeah sorry, I noticed I got it wrong way round and changed it.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` points to a `div` and there's no `.submit()` function for a div, so you cannot replace it.